Origin of "snipe" to mean "partially-smoked cigar(ette)"?
I was recently in a smoke shop to buy some rolling papers. After I asked the clerk for a specific brand, the clerk said to another, "there's an unopened carton of them behind the snipe holders". The second clerk reached behind a display of what I would call "cigarette savers" (a writing-pen-shaped metal tube with a flip cap, used for storing a single cigarette) and opened up a pack of the rolling papers I'd asked for.
I've now gathered from a few sources (1, 2) that "snipe" is an old slang term referring to a cigarette butt, or an otherwise discarded partially-smoked cigarette (or cigar).
The word "guttersnipe" seems likely to be related, on account of its meaning "one who gathers rags and paper from gutters"... but I haven't been able to find a definitive etymology, and am curious where it comes from.
edit: I've done a little more digging, and I'm starting to piece together a more direct connection between the slang "cigarette" usage and something with a more concrete, literal definition.
I found this definition on Wiktionary: "An end of a log remaining after timber has been cut away - sometimes referred to as a snipe-end". It doesn't take a large leap of the imagination to connect the image of a stump of a chopped-down tree to the shape of an unfinished cigarette... but there's no primary source on that Wiktionary definition.
There's also this discussion on an arborist's web forum: https://www.arboristsite.com/threads/homboldt-with-a-snipe.58936/, lending more believability to the idea that it is, indeed, a timber-related word.
Going on, I found this other usage I'd never heard before: https://library.municode.com/fl/jacksonville/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=TITXXIPUWOUT_CH741ZETOLI. This is the Jacksonville, FL Code of Ordinances sec. 741.102(d), which says:

The term "snipe sign" shall mean a sign which is tacked, nailed, posted, pasted, glued, or otherwise attached or affixed to a tree on public property, to a public utility pole, to a public utility box, to publicly-owned street furniture such as a bench or shelter, to a public fence

I find this the most interesting clue yet, because it directly combines two previous definitions: one usage for timber, and one for garbage, trash, and other unwanted scraps.
While my own amateur research is, by no means, authoritative, and I have yet to see a succinct, conclusive answer along the lines of, "it's 19th-century hobo slang for a cigarette butt, owing to the fact that many of these men had previously worked in lumbermills and adopted the term because cigarette butts look like logs", I'm willing to settle until an actual historian/linguist comes along and provides some verifiable facts.

I suspect there is a connection with the bird (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe). Guttersnipe may refer to its method of feeding, and snipe holders to the long narrow shape of its bill. I haven't searched for evidence at this stage.

This is not an answer, but... it seems snipe might be related to snout. If you watch a snipe bird video, you can see the snipe using its long beak-snout to pick out/pick up/pick off its target. Perhaps @SvenYargs will come sniffing around to provide an answer.

The US slang sense The discarded stub of a cigar or cigarette was first recorded 1891, some decades after earlier metaphoric usage A child brought up ‘in the gutter’; one of the lowest class; an urchin, first recorded 1869. Curiously, the more "literal" sense (dialectal) The common snipe, Gallinago cælestis (Northumbld. Gloss. 1893). b. The common American or Wilson's snipe, Gallinago wilsoni or delicata was first recorded a bit later, in 1874. But mire-snipe (Scottish) The common snipe was first recorded 1525, and figurative meet with a mire-snipe = have a mishap in 1667.

...there was also gutter-bird The sparrow, hence figurative, a disreputable person, first recorded 1895. And of snipe itself (first recorded 1325) the full OED says Probably a borrowing from early Scandinavian. Of doubtful origin: the Middle English type snīpe corresponds to a Scandinavian snīpa recorded in Icelandic mýrisnípa, Norwegian myr-, strandsnipa. It is not clear how this is related to Middle Dutch snippe (Dutch and West Frisian snip), Middle Low German and Low German (also older Danish) snippe, German dialect schnippe... and on and on and on....

...Google Books has 3 relevant instances of "snipe holder", but unsurprisingly for such a rare collocation, searching the Internet at large for define "snipe holder" returns nothing useful. And I'm sure there's no etymological connection between snipe and the long-established (prison) slang snout = tobacco, cigarettes

for whatever it’s worth, here’s another somewhat recent (five years old) occurrence of the term, from a product review on amazon.com: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/review/B07NN4VX2W/R322H84WBNC6I5

Snipe as a term of abuse is found in Othello (c. 1603). The OED's earliest reference to the cigarette use is 1891 "The ‘Snipe-Shooter’ was guilty of smoking cigar-stubs picked out of the gutter, a habit known among the boys as ‘snipe-shooting’." (H. Campbell, Darkness & Daylight) So it might derive by analogy with a sniper in the military sense, for someone who spots from afar and targets? Never quite sure how comprehensive the OED's coverage of slang is though, and this might be someone adding the shooting sense to an older meaning of snipe.

Obviously guttersnipe is "related" - there was only ever one word snipe (originally, just the bird) from which everything else is derived. OED has the first instance of the verb use at 1782: Now people have been shot by platoons and in corps, the individual will be popped at or sniped, as they call it, from time to time. But what exactly is being asked here? Even the OED says the origin of snipe is "obscure", and is there really any point in asking how snipe = partly-smoked cigar / cigarette, "dog-end" came about? Presumably via guttersnipe = beggar.

I’m voting to close this question because I don't see what anyone can usefully add to what dictionaries say that's not just "opinions"

@FumbleFingers — A scholar could at least look up the citation for the statement: The Old English “snite” and Middle English “snype” is related to the word “snout.” Citation: Greenoak, F., All The Birds of the Air, 2nd ed, (Middlesex: Penguin Books Ltd., 1981), 119.

@TinfoilHat: I see nothing in the (extremely long) full OED etymologies for snipe and snout to support that connection. As pointed out above, for snipe they say Probably a borrowing from early Scandinavian. Of doubtful origin and for the very much older snout they say: A word inherited from Germanic.
Middle English snūt(e, = West Frisian snút, snute (North Frisian snüt, snit), Middle Dutch snūte, snuut (Kilian snuyte, Dutch snuit), Middle Low German snût(e, German schnauze (†schnausze, schnauz) ... The early history of these forms is somewhat obscure...

@FumbleFingers — 1. Entry status for snipe: OED is undergoing a continuous programme of revision to modernize and improve definitions. This entry has not yet been fully revised. 2. Look up snite in the OED.

I've had enough of this one. I think the OP just wants someone to spell out how guttersnipe = street urchin leads to snipe holder = (single) cigarette case and thus on to snipe = dog-end, cigar stub (as in the lyrics of "King of the Road" I smoke old stogies I have found
Short, but not too big around
I'm a man of means by no means
King of the road

Hi @FumbleFingers. Is the purpose of the English Language & Usage forum not for etymologies to be discussed and "spelled out"? It's hard to tell whether you think this is a bad thing. I merely encountered an unusual term, found it interesting, and wanted to know if there's a concrete origin for "snipe == discarded unfinished cigarette". I've found some related terms, but their connections are tenuous. Perhaps most interesting so far is this other definition of "snipe": "an end of a log remaining after timber has been cut away". A log "butt" would indeed resemble a cigarette butt.

@UnseemlyKong — You'd have to find much earlier usage for a logging connection; the OED's first attestation in the logging sense is 1958 — a far cry from cigarettes butts at 1891.

Early dictionary coverage of 'snipe' in the sense of 'partially smoked cigar(ette)'
James Maitland, The American Slang Dictionary (1891) has this relevant entry for snipe from an era before cigarettes were the nicotine vessel of choice in the United States:
Snipe, the butt of a cigar.
Maitland also has entries for snipe in the senses of "an impertinent boy," "in stock exchange slang, a curbstone broker," "applied to a tailor's bill, from its extreme length," and "to steal." In addition Maitland offers this evocative entry:


Snipe-hunting, going round the streets looking for cigar ends.


J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present (1903) concurs in part, although it offers several other definitions as well:

Snipe. subs. (old). 1. A thin thing, male or female; in Americas = a small child. 2. (old) = a simpleton ; SNIPE-KNAVE (Cotgrave): 'So called because two of them are worth but one SNIPE.' ... 3. (old).—A lawyer : hence (4) a long bill. 5. (thieves').—in pl. = the fingers. ... 6. (Old Cant).—Scissors (Grose). 7. (American street).—A half-smoked cigar.8. (American S. Exchange).—A curbstone broker; a GUTTERSNIPE;.] Verb. (military).—To fire at random into a camp.

Interestingly, just fourteen years earlier, J.S. Farmer, Americanisms—Old and New: A Dictionary of Words, Phrases & Colloquialisms Peculiar to the United States, British America, The West Indies, &c., &c. (1889) included only the curbstone broker meaning of snipe.
Maurice Weseen, Dictionary of American Slang (1934) offers several area-specific entries for snipe in the smoking sense. From "Hoboes and Tramps":

Snipe—A section hand; a cigar or cigarette end; to steal.
...
Snipe shooter—A person who picks up discarded ends of cigars and cigarettes.

From "College":

Snipe—a cigarette.

And from "General":

Snipe—To pry into the affairs of another person; a dunce.
Snipe hunter—A victim of a practical joke.


Early instances of 'snipe' in the wild
A search for relevant instances of snipe in the Chronicling America database of old newspapers turns up this interesting instance, from "Jargon of Thieves: The Peculiarity of Criminal's Palaver," in the [Austin, Texas] Weekly Democratic Statesman (August 17, 1882):

In wider application of the term, "cat" is applied generally to women, though it is restricted among the more aesthetic criminals to loose women. A blow of the fist or club is a "slug," a loaf of bread is a "dummy," and the end of a cigar is a "snipe." Small boys who gather cigar stumps are called "snipe-hunters," a term also applied to an objectionable person to indicate that he is very low or degraded.

Also of interest is this instance from "Snipe-Hunting," reprinted from the Chicago [Illinois] Tribune in in the [Medicine Lodge, Kansas] Barbour County Index (April 13, 1883):

"The Champion Snipe-Hunter in America" haunts the Grand Pacific and other hotels daily, and he has done so for the last two weeks or more. "The Snipe-hunter" is none of your fellows who walk about the marshes with gun, powder and shot, but he is the man who "snipes the soldier." "The soldier" is the veteran remains of a cigar—one that has been smoked to satisfaction by the original owner and thrown upon the ground or in the spittoon to be used no more—so at least the man who discards it thinks. The subject of this paragraph is no outcast tramp in filthy rages, but a respectable-appearing man. He wears good clothes and he carries in technical parlance "a snipe and a slang." He is apparently about fifty-five years old, with gray beard and mustache. He wears an excellent overcoat and boots and a sealskin turban. His modus operandi is very ingenious. From afar he espies "the soldier," be he in marble hall or in tobacco-juice tesselated spittoon. He pulls out his pocket-handkerchief, drops it over his prisoner, and victoriously deposits him in his coat-pocket, where he is held prisoner until some secluded spot is reached, when he is bagged with the previously-captured game. "The snipe-hunter" sports an elegant meershaum cigar-holder, highly colored, and from this the prisoners are in part evaporated into smoke.

Regrettably, I could not uncover any information regarding what "a snipe and a slang" meant "in technical parlance" in the early 1880s—although the 1882 Austin newspaper article cited above reports that "a super and a slang" means "a watch and chain."
The earliest match for "snipe" as "cigar butt" appears to be this one, from "The Army of Tramps," in the [Bel Air, Maryland] Aegis & Intelligencer (May 17, 1878):

If things continue as they are we will soon have a standing army of tramps, as they are on the increase every day. A crowd was seen the other day having a fire built and cooking their dinner in an old lime kiln belonging to Mr. Mechem of this place. Their dinner consisted of coffee and some greens and potatoes about the size f a penny marble, which they no doubt dug out of some truck patch on their line of march. They have very peculiar phrases in their language; for instance they say, "I shot a snipe," whenever they find a cigar stump, and "I fried an oyster," whenever they get victuals to ear at a house, &c.

And from a brief item in the Tiffin [Ohio] Tribune (February 13, 1879):

An Amusing Sight.—To see the tramps after being let out of the Station house, coming up Market street, "shooting snipes"—cigar stubs.

An early discussion of the connection between snipes and cigarettes appears in "Local and General" in the Lebanon [Oregon] Express (October 21, 1887):

Boys who smoke cigarettes—and Lebanon, we regret to say, has a number of them—may be interested in knowing that these "dainty stinkers" are made from what is known in the eastern factories as "snipes"—the ends of cigar stubs thrown into the gutters and gathered up by the Italian lazzaroni that make ragpicking a business.The article is flavored with double extract of assafoedita and vulture livers, and is most deadly in its influence upon the nerves and brain. If boys will smoke they ought to use cigars or decent tobacco, and not take the chances of destroying their eyesight and paralyzing their brain by sucking these poisonous "snipes."

Even earlier is this untitled item originally from the San Francisco [California] Chronicle, reprinted in the [Globe City] Arizona Silver Belt (July 18, 1885):

The San Francisco Chronicle says: There are a number of men in this city, as in all others of equal size, who earn livings by collecting cigar butts and cigarette "snipes." The haunts of the gay, the busy marts of commerce, and the abodes of the evil all supply merchandise for the cigar-butt merchant. The butts and snipe are sold to Chinese cigarette makers, who granulate the filthy stuff, flavor it slightly, roll it in neat papers, put up the cigarettes in packages flaringly lithographed, and dispose of them where the small boy parts with his nickels and health for their possession.

The association of children with cigarette smoking is quite strong in early newspaper accounts, along with the supposed origin of cigarette tobacco as refurbished cigar butt tobacco and the especial perniciousness of inhaling cigarette fumes, contrary to standard practice with cigars.
At least one fairly early account describes discarded cigar butts as "gutter-snipes." From "The Station-House Lodging-Room," in the [Honolulu, Hawaii] Pacific Commercial Advertiser (July 11, 1889):

The air is sickening. It is filled with fumes of vile liquor. The spirit which brought nearly all of these people here broods over them and drives a decent stomach to rebellion. Luckily many of the men upon the shelf are smoking violently at pipes and cheap cigars and gutter-snipes picked up on the streets. The tobacco smoke, dense and choking though it is, is a comparative blessing here, as it is in the dissecting room.

But a subsequent article in the same newspaper less than four years later uses "gutter-snipe" to refer to a person who collects snipes. From "The Gutter Snipe Here," in the Honolulu, Hawaii] Pacific Commercial Advertiser (March 4, 1889):

The "gutter-snipe" has made his appearance on Honolulu's streets, and as a scavenger of cigar stumps and cigarette ends is proving himself an adept in this queer "profession." Shortly after the noon hour, when business men were on their way to their offices, after lunching and obtaining solace from their noon day cigar, the "gutter-snipe" showed himself. He was a white man, but with face and hands and shoeless and stockingless feet so caked with dirt that he looked more mulatto than white skinned. His clothes were in keeping with his skin.
The man began his trail from Queen street, skirting the curb along Fort street to King. Like a hound on the scent, the "gutter-snipe" ferreted out cigar stumps, some cold and some still smouldering. The burning ends were rubbed against the stone curbing, and when all signs of fire had vanished they were deposited in his coat pockets. Dirty cigars and cigarettes, again fouled by contact with the street, all found their way into his pockets which soon bulged. In front of Nolte's, Martin's, and Waterhouse's the "snipe" reaped a harvest.


Assessment
Confirmed newspaper instances of snipe used in the sense of "cigar stub"—and explicitly attributed to the lingo of tramps—go back to 1878 at least. There is considerable variation in usage in the period from 1879 to 1903, however, as sometimes the "snipe" is the cigar (or cigarette) butt and sometimes it is the butt collector, who at other times is the "snipe-hunter," the "snipe shooter," or the "gutter-snipe."
Likewise the non-human "snipe" is sometimes the discarded butt, sometimes the ground-up amalgam of such butts, and sometimes reconstituted cigarettes of gutter origin sold in packets as if fresh and new. One account presents the cigar butts as "soldiers" that the collector "snipes" (by finding and picking them up).
According to Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003), snipe as an intransitive verb meaning "to shoot at exposed individuals (as of an enemy's forces) from a usu[ally] concealed point of vantage" dates to 1832, and I see no reason to reject the possibility that the tramp slang term "shooting snipe" was influenced by "sniping" in this sense as well as by the metaphor of hunting elusive marsh birds—especially in view of how surreptitiously these early "snipe hunters" pursued their prey in two of the newspaper accounts cited above.
With regard to snipe as a term in the logging/timber industry, the earliest newspaper match I could find for "snipe" in close proximity to "timber" or "log" was the following instance from an untitled item in the [Shelton, Washington Territory] Mason County Journal (August 10, 1894):

George Murphy, hooktender at Orin Winters' camp was brought down Tuesday morning having inflicted a bad cut on his right limb with an axe, while "sniping" a log.

This instance appears a little over sixteen years after the mention in the Bel Air, Maryland, newspaper of "I shot a snipe" meaning, in tramp talk, "I found a cigar stump." The proposed migration of "snipe" from the timber trade to tramp slang is not a good fit with this chronology, although earlier instances of "sniping" used among loggers might make the connection more credible.
